# Is FireBird still alive?

Tags: firebird

I am looking for some embedded databases. SQLite has some issues with the GUI. What about FireBird? How active is it's mailing list and forums? Does it follow all the rules of ANSI SQL? Is it suitable for production?

Comment: If you are using a .NET based language, SQLite or Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition would be a good choice.

Comment: What do you mean "SQLite has some issues with the GUI"?

Comment: SQLite's GUI browser is not feature rich and also I didn't find anyway to create a composite key using the GUI.

Comment: Creating composite keys is something that you should only do Very Rarely >;-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Is Firebird still alive? Are you kidding? It is only few weeks since Firebird 2.5 has been [launched](http://firebirdsql.org/pop/pop_pressRelease25.html). We use it in our commercial products both ways, as a client server and as an embedded solution. We found it stable, powerfull and SQL compliant. Comparing with MSSQL there are two significant advantages.

1. Firebird is free;
2. Firebird is cross-platform.

Comment: Which front-end you use? Is there any full feature-rich GUI to manage even a single file embedded db?

Comment: If by "GUI" here you mean some utility for managing metadata, run queries, do database maintenance etc. then we use IBExpert. http://ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Main.IBExpert

Comment: Firebird does have a gui flamerobin works with embedded here is one old tutorial for 1.5.x but you get the idea http://pabloj.blogspot.com/2006/08/flamerobin-as-gui-for-embedded.html

Comment: Also the EMS SQL Management Studio for InterBase/Firebird is very good. http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products/studio/ibfb .  I am using firebird for commercial applications both the embedded and client-server version and it works fine. Especially the client-server is very easy to install, installs in a few seconds, it is just a few megabytes (less than 10mb if I remember good) and it is ready to use after installation without any configuration. The community is very active. Firebird is highly recommended for your database needs.

Answer (score 6):

I come from a primarily microsoft based background and typically work in C#, asp.net and sql server. I recently started working with firebird for one of my clients.  I am enjoying working with it and I am using a tool called databaseworkbench for gui administration right now.  I also here that IbExpert is a good gui admin tool. I plan to try it out and there are many others.  I actually did not care much for the FlameRobin tool at all but that's just my personal opinion.

In my opinion if firebird shipped with a great built-in gui admin tool it would be much more popular. People struggle to figure out which gui admin tool to use and the gui admin tool you choose highly controls how you perceive firebird as a database because different gui admin tools offer different features and functionality.  So far so good though here.  The client I am working for right now has about 800 companies running the firebird db as a backend successfully.

Answer (score 4):

Going to Firebird web site and checking their news, releases, and bigfix list will give you an idea how active it is. I am very pleased with Firebird and I can recommend it without blinking.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. firebird is alive with new featurea.
I'm using it on production for long time and big tables

Comment: How would you rate it in terms of performance and stability when comparing with MySQL and PostgreSQL? I hope it doesn't require a dedicated DBA like Oracle?

Comment: I tested performance vs postgresql long time ago and results were ok

Comment: I tested performance vs postgresql long time ago and results were ok. mysql lacks many features compared to firebird or postgresql. One of the reasons i'm using firebird it's low or null administration or maintenance. YOu can install and run firebird in few minuts. I use flamerobin to administrate and create the databases. ibexpert is a great tool, but I prefer flamerobin because is free, small and multyplatform

Answer (score 1):

dbvisualizer works pretty well with firebird.

I have found firebird to be pretty reliable. However, there are some gotchas.

Eg,

Select first 10 * from table_a;

instead of

select * from table_a limit 10;

Using an orm to talk to db usually takes care of these differences.

Answer (score 0):

I think, [Firebird Development Studio](http://www.sqlly.com/) from SQLLY is close to something called IDE for `Firebird RDBMS` (regardless of the bugs that I encountered while using it), I haven't found other tools that has a `refactoring` feature that very helpful at development stage.